# Can I Instruct Windows 7 to Not Write a Single Bit of Data on Windows Partition?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I want to install windows 7 on a SSD or thumb drive and after that the windows should not write a single bit of data to that partition.

For all the configuration and log files windows should choose another drive(only window registry writing is allowed). Is that possible and if yes how to achieve that.

Comment: Why are you concerned with limiting writes to a SSD? Modern SSDs have write limits that you will never reach.

Comment: Agreed with @George.  Maybe if this was a thumb drive I could understand (but then it will be painfully slow) but on an SSD this would be silly.

Comment: thanks for your time @George it is not for why, it is for how anyway

Answer (score 3):

> the windows should not write a single bit of data to that partition. is that possible

No. Everything gets logged to [MFT](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/ntfs/archMFT-c.html) and it's not at all possible. Best you can do is probably move the pagefile to a separate drive, which is counterproductive.

Comment: i am saying if all the writing can be stopped on a single volume then MFT will not be changed i think. Only registry and related activities can be recorded on that drive.

Comment: Registry related activities writes, file transfers will result in changes to MFT

Comment: i already said all the crucial registry related changes are allowed whether it is MFT or anything.

Comment: I've also said - `Best you can do is probably move the pagefile to a separate drive, which is counterproductive`.